# How does $1.20\min(X,n)−n=1.20\min(X−n,0)+0.2n$?

Tags: functions

I don't understand how these 2 expression can be equal$$1.20\min(X,n)−n=1.20\min(X−n,0)+0.2n$$

Comment: **Hint:** Note that $\min(a+c,b+c)=c+\min(a,b)$ holds for all reals $a,b,c$ and we can rewrite the expression in the LHS as $1.20(\min(X,n)-n)+0.2n$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\begin{align*} & 1.20\min\{X,n\}−n
\\[1ex] ~=~& 1.20\min\{X,n\}-(1.20-0.2)n \tag 1
\\[1ex] ~=~& 1.20\big(\min\{X,n\}-n\big)+0.2 n \tag 2
\\[1ex] ~=~& 1.20\min\{X−n,0\}+0.2n \tag 3
\end{align*}$

Is there a step you cannot follow?